# "He got a new best friend [punctuation] himself"

Tags: punctuation

First time asking a question here. I thought of this sentence just a few moments ago, and I can't figure out how to properly punctuate it so that it conveys the meaning I had intended.

*He got a new best friend, [namely] himself"*

How would this be punctuated properly? I'm personally leaning towards comma, but maybe semicolon or even full stop is a better idea? Thanks in advance, and sorry about what is probably a fairly simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma is the usual choice in this construction. However, if you are looking for some more emphasis, an em-dash would also be appropriate, as it conveys a long pause, but not the end/start of a sentence.

He got a new best friend—himself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I especially appreciate the explanation about the em-dash — a capricious form of punctuation I've avoided for long.

Comment: Careful here, there should *not* be spaces around an em-dash. See *Chicago Manual of Style* § 6.85.

Comment: I think a colon might also be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much you two! In my native language, Norwegian, there is a space before and after the em-dash, hence the confusion.